# Django rest api and axios post request don't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I am trying to make a simple api where a user writes something in an input, presses a button and a new instance is added in a database. To do this I am using react and django rest framework.

App.js

```
const [name,setName] = useState('')
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

  function handleClick(e) {
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/', {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'X-CSRFToken': 'csrftoken'
      },
      data:{
        title: name,
        name: name
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type='text' value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>OK</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def home2(request):
    serializer = ItemSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('api/',views.home,name='home'),
path('post/',views.home2,name='home2'),
path('a/',views.home3,name='home3')
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'main',
    'corsheaders'
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

But when I press the button I get

manifest.json:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest.json 404 (Not Found) and

manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error. in javascript.

In django I get

"POST /post/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 Also I am using npm run build for javascript and manifest.json is in public folder.

React is inside django and the structure looks like this:

mysite
frontend
main
mysite
db.sqlite3
manage.py

Also when I try to make a new instance from "/post" (home2) I get in cmd

Method Not Allowed: /post/
"POST /post/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5588

Answer (score 0):

you did not show your Serializer or DB (Model) here but here is a full working example;
To make things clearer for you my answer will include the Django Models, Serializer and the views and urls for the Api Call.
In the Model, i added two more fields one for the Item ID and a time stamp. In a real world application, you would have some logic for generating the Item IDs every other thing is standard boilerplate for Django models and you can get more info from
[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/)

Here is your Model:

```
class Items(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
item_id=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,unique=False)    

class Meta:

    verbose_name = _('Item')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Items')
    ordering = ['pk']

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Serializer: Just a standard model serializer to go with your Function Based View. I added validation to check if an Item ID Already exists.

```
   class ItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
    model = Items
    fields = ['name', 'item_id', ]  
def save(self):
    name = self.validated_data['name']
    item_id = self.validated_data['item_id']  
   
    new_item = Items(name=name, item_id=item_id) 
    
    if  Items.objects.filter(item_id=item_id).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            {"error": "Sorry, An Item With This ID Already Exists"})
    else:            
        new_item.save()
        return new_item
```

View: Standard as well similar to yours

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
@permission_classes([])
@authentication_classes([])
def api_save_new_item(request):
data = {}    

if request.method == 'POST':

    serializer = ItemsSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        new_item = serializer.save()           
        data['message'] = "Successfully Saved New Item"
        data['status'] = 'Success!'
        data['code'] = status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        data['item_id'] = new_item.item_id
        data['name'] = new_item.name      

    else:
        data = serializer.errors           
return Response(data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED,)
```

Urs.py:

```
path('api_save_new_item/',api_save_new_item,name='api_save_new_item'),
```

React: similar to yours as well. I am accessing the data off the ustate call and passing to the axios call.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
const client = axios.create({
baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
});

export const AddNewItems = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [id, setID] = useState("");
const handleNameChange = (e: any) => {
setName(e.target.value);
};
const handleIdChange = (e: any) => {
setID(e.target.value);
};
function handleClick(e: any) {
 client
  .post("/api/api_save_new_item/", {
    name: name,
    item_id: id,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }

  return (
   <>
  <form onSubmit={(event) => event.preventDefault()}>
    <label htmlFor="name">Item Name</label>
    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
    <br />
    <label htmlFor="itemid">Item ID</label>
    <input type="text" value={id} onChange={handleIdChange} />
    <br />
    <button onClick={handleClick}>OK</button>
  </form>
 </>
);
```

};

everything works fine here

see the response

```
{
"message": "Successfully Saved New Item",
"status": "Success!",
"code": 201,
"item_id": "ID009",
"name": "Woks"
```

}

so, hope this helps, I know its been a while you asked this question.